# Angular scope, controller, describe function and it function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

couple questions while i was going through the tutorial that i cannot find the answer to.
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02

1)in View and Template, how does {{phone}} bind to the controller? and what are the ng-controller and ng-app?

2)whats the $scope in Model and Controller?

3)further down in the Testing section, what is the describe function, it function, and what does {$scope: scope} mean in Testing non-global controllers? 
4)what does the $ mean in $scope, $injector, etc

Comment: Have you tried to have a read through the angular docs or maybe watched some videos explaining angular? Those are mostly core concepts that you've missed. The describe and it functions are part of the Jasmine test framework.

Comment: And the tutorial explains how `{{ }}` interpolation works. Please do basic research before asking questions here

Answer (score 0):

You've clearly didn't put enough effort in researching but here's my answer:

1. `{{phone}}` binds to the controller via the `$scope`. `$scope` is a concept by angular connecting the controller and the view via binding. everything on the `$scope` is visible on the template. `ng-controller` is a **directive** that when specified - lets the element and its children share a common controller. `ng-app` defines the first module angular loads - the "app".
2. `$scope` is the "glue" between the view and the controller allowing all sorts of binding and is the "magic" behind `{{phone}}`.
3. `describe` describes the purpose of the testing unit. `it` describes what the particular test should do.